# How to extract certain rows in R without running through the whole data again and again

Tags: r, subset, extract, rows

I have a data frame (df) which has 2.5 million rows. Sample data frame looks like this:

```
PERMNO <- c(10000,10000,10001,10001,10001,10001, 10002,10002,10002)

TICKER <- c('OMFGA','OMFGA', 'GFGC', 'GFGC', 'GFGC', 'GFGC', 'MBNC', 'MBNC', 'MBNC')

date <- as.Date(c('1986-03-31','1986-04-30','1986-01-31', '1986-01-31', '1986-03-31', '1986-04-30', '1986-04-30','1986-05-30', '1986-05-30'))

df = data.frame(PERMNO, date, TICKER)
```

In this example, there are 3 unique PERMNO. Now I need to extract all the data for the given PERMNO, and check if there are any duplicate dates. My intention is to remove rows with duplicate dates for a particular PERMNO. This operation I do for all the unique PERMNO

My approach: I am using subset function to extract data for a particular PERMNO and then checking for duplicates in dates. But using this approach, my code runs through the entire data everytime (2.5 million rows in original dataset) to extract data for a particular PERMNO. Is there any shorter way to do this? As I have 22000 unique PERMNO, the code is taking forever to run in the For loop.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
uniqueperm = unique(df$PERMNO)

lenperm = length(uniqueperm)

data_final = df[FALSE,]  

for(i in 1:lenperm){

        perm = uniqueperm[i]
        df1 = filter(df, PERMNO == perm) 
        df1 = subset(df1,!duplicated(df1$date))
        data_final = rbind(data_final,df1)
        df1 = df1[FALSE,]
} 

data_final
```

Comment: Isn't that just a duplicate on `PERMNO` and `date` then if you're looking for duplicates on `date` inside each `PERMNO` subset? I.e. `duplicated(df[c("PERMNO","date")])` Or am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: Can you add your code (For loop) so we have something to reference?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you're running, I get what you're describing but it would be much easier to see it precisely.

Comment: I added the code I'm using @jamzsabb

Comment: @thelatemail . Your suggestion worked well for a small dataset. Just that when I try to apply it to my original dataset of 2.5 million rows, it's taking forever to run. I used this code:  array_logic= duplicated(df[c("PERMNO","date")])  
r = length(array_logic)   
newdf = df[FALSE,]  <br/>
for(i in 1:r){ <br/>
        if(array_logic[i]==FALSE) { <br/>
                newdf = rbind(newdf,df[i,]) <br/>
        }<br/>
}<br/>
nrow(newdf)<br/>

Comment: @DenaG - that's because you're not using it as intended. There is no need for a loop at all - literally just `df[!duplicated(df[c("PERMNO","date")]),]` should do it. Not blazingly fast, but finished in 25 seconds on a 2.5M row dataset.

Comment: @thelatemail ...this worked..I'm so glad. Thank you so much. It's the most simplified approach.

Answer (score 3):

This should be reasonably quick for all but massive datasets:

```
df[!duplicated(df[c("PERMNO","date")]),]
#  PERMNO       date TICKER
#1  10000 1986-03-31  OMFGA
#2  10000 1986-04-30  OMFGA
#3  10001 1986-01-31   GFGC
#5  10001 1986-03-31   GFGC
#6  10001 1986-04-30   GFGC
#7  10002 1986-04-30   MBNC
#8  10002 1986-05-30   MBNC
```

A basic timing on similar data to what you have:

```
df2 <- data.frame(PERMNO=sample(1:22000,2.5e6,replace=TRUE), date=1:2.5e6)
nrow(df2)
#[1] 2500000
length(unique(df2$PERMNO))
#[1] 22000
system.time(df2[!duplicated(df2[c("PERMNO","date")]),])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.48    0.08    3.56
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster than a for-loop for a large data-set:

```
dates <- lapply(split(df, df$PERMNO), '[[', "date") 
df2 <-mapply(function(x,y)x[!y,], 
           split(df,df$PERMNO), 
           lapply(dates, duplicated), 
           SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

do.call(rbind, df2)

#         PERMNO       date TICKER
# 10000.1  10000 1986-03-31  OMFGA
# 10000.2  10000 1986-04-30  OMFGA
# 10001.3  10001 1986-01-31   GFGC
# 10001.5  10001 1986-03-31   GFGC
# 10001.6  10001 1986-04-30   GFGC
# 10002.7  10002 1986-04-30   MBNC
# 10002.8  10002 1986-05-30   MBNC
```

Comment: I tried this code. It's taking very long. Looking for something that will run faster.